# Манипуляции с элементом, когда он появляется в поле зрения по центру?

Tags: html, jquery, css, веб-программирование

Сейчас код такой:

```
function aboutUsAmination() {
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        var aboutUs = $('.about_us');
        var top = $(aboutUs).offset().top;
        var scrollFromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollFromTop >= top) {
          console.log("Hello")
        }

    });

};
```

В консоль выводится сообщение когда мы непосредственно доскролили до блока(то есть, он в самом верху экрана). Мне нужно, что бы хотя бы когда он по середине экрана. Можно вычислить точное число и отнимать его от top, но это нужно будет отнимать для каждого разрешения экрана. 

**И так: Как вывести в консоль сообщение, когда блок по вертикали по центру, а не вверху**

Comment: Ставим вот так: 
var top = $(aboutUs).offset().top / 2;

Comment: @NeedHate не совсем так решил вопрос, но спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого - скорректруйте `scrollFromTop` на половину высоты окна, а `top` - на половину высоты блока:

```
function aboutUsAmination() {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var aboutUs = $('.about_us');
        var top = $block.offset().top + $block.outerHeight() / 2;
        var scrollFromTop = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() / 2;
        if (scrollFromTop >= top) {
          console.log("Hello")
        }
    });
};
```

При таком варианте - сообщение в консоли вы увидите, когда середина блока окажется по вертикали посередине, или выше.

[Рабочий пример на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/va7pavee/)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Остановился на этом варианте   if (scrollFromTop >= (top - aboutUs.height() / 2)) {

Comment: Еще лучше их будет совместить. У `scrollFromTop` отнимать половину высоты экрана, а к `top` - прибавлять половину высоты блока. Тогда скрипт будет срабатывать, когда середина блока будет проходить через середину экрана - что сделает скрипт, в разумных пределах, универсальным и для разных разрешений экрана, и для разных высот блоков.

Comment: Сейчас попробую эту смесь)

Comment: var scrollFromTop = $(window).scrollTop() - $(window).height() / 2;

  if (scrollFromTop >= (top + aboutUs.height() / 2)) {
Так не вышло. Скрипт срабатывает когда мы достигли половины всей страницы

Comment: Да, вы правы - я перепутал знак, в обоих случаях должно идти прибавление. Дополнил ответ и приложил ссылку на jsfiddle

Comment: Спасибо большое за труд!)